# c# Controls in list and accessing ListBox Properties

Tags: c#, listbox, controls

I have solved a problem I was having with grouping objects in a way, that at beginning of the program, I loop trough all controls and store all `TextBox` and `ListBoxes` in a `List<Controls>`.
When i try to access them i do:

```
foreach(var g in controlsList)
{
   g.Text = "VALUE";
}
```

and that works, but when I try to do `g.SelectedIndex = 0` its wrong, I am guessing that has to do with that property being specific to `listBox`. How do I solve, or get around that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
foreach (var c in Controls)
{
    var listBox = c as ListBox;
    if (listBox != null)
    {
        listBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }
}
```

Each control is safely cast to a `ListBox`. If it is not, the result will be `null` and will be skipped by the if block.

Comment: Your answer helped me solved it, I added a ListBox variable to which I have assigned "g as ListBox"  so "ListBox pom = g as ListBox;" With that new "pom" variable i could access the needed property.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use `OfType` to filter Controls:

```
foreach(ListBox l in Controls.OfType<ListBox>()) 
    l.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

To access that property you have to cast to destination type first:

```
foreach(var control in controlsList)
{
    if(control is ListBox) // check if this control is a listbox
       ((ListBox)control).SelectedIndex = 0; // now it is save to cast to listbox
}
```

the same could be done using as operator:

```
foreach(var control in controlsList)
{
    var listBox = control as ListBox;
    if(listBox != null) // check if cast was ok
       listBox.SelectedIndex = 0; // use listBox
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You're right that the property is specific to the list box.
You need to cast this to the correct object to be able to access it.

Here's an example:

```
foreach(var c in controlsList)
{
    c.Text = "VALUE";
    if (c is ListBox)
    {
        ListBox listBox = c as ListBox;
        listBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it is quicker to read then using `as` and checking for `null`.  personal preference.  what's wrong with it? @TomSchardt